# Make migrated posts be part of chat RSS feed

Tags: feature-request, migration, chat, feed

One advantage of living on a per-site chat channel is that you get to see all new questions. The ones I miss are those that are migrated to the site.

I once saw something similar to what I requested on [unix-SE chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26), but the bad formatting had me assume that the devs were testing the feature.

Comment: This would be useful, especially as migrated questions require attention more often than most.

Comment: Sorry about the flag, but this is in fact *not* status-completed.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening inconsistently, and I can't find the pattern. Looking at Unix.SE's recent imports:

- [From SO 2011-05-05 17:21:44](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5901736/vmware-tools-on-fedora?noredirect=1), [migrated 2011-05-06 13:10:48](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12733/vmware-tools-on-fedora), never fed
- [From SF 2011-05-06 22:23:10](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12782/where-nautilus-gnome-keeps-track-or-log-of-user-activity), [migrated 2011-05-07 02:33:33](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12782/where-nautilus-gnome-keeps-track-or-log-of-user-activity), never fed
- [From AU 2011-05-07 13:08:19](https://askubuntu.com/questions/40981/perfect-distro-for-an-old-mac-desktop-ppc-g3-320mb-ram?noredirect=1), [migrated 2011-05-07 14:04:47](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12794/perfect-distro-for-an-old-mac-desktop-ppc-g3-320mb-ram), [fed 14:12:02](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/944044#944044)
- [From SO 2011-04-04 23:21:02](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5545446/hiding-a-zsh-completion?noredirect=1), [migrated 2011-05-07 15:55:18](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12797/hiding-a-zsh-completion), never fed
- [From SF 2011-05-07 20:19:53](https://serverfault.com/questions/267366/why-are-pid-and-lock-files-for?noredirect=1), [migrated 2011-05-07 20:41:18](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12815/why-are-pid-and-lock-files-for), [fed 20:52:59](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/26?m=945254#945254)