# Can questions migrated from trilogy sites to small sites have votes zeroed?

Tags: feature-request, vote-count

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reset votes on migrated questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87031/reset-votes-on-migrated-questions)

When questions are migrated to Security SE, even if they have been open on a trilogy site for a couple of hours they may have 20 or more votes - which on Security is rarely beaten.

These answers may not be correct in a security context, or may be partially correct.

What would work is if the votes could be zeroed out so the security community can assess and vote on the answers without the order being heavily skewed.

I'm guessing this problem must be common to the smaller sites - although I didn't find any duplicate of this so I'm unsure.

Comment: Just curious: Is this the one in question?: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/11025/what-should-i-do-when-my-boss-asks-me-to-fabricate-audit-log-data

Comment: @Madmartigan - one of them, yes :-)

Comment: Wasn't sure which site all those votes came from, looking at the [original](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/131771/what-should-i-do-when-my-boss-asks-me-to-fabricate-audit-log-data?noredirect=1), seems like there were only 15 votes when it was migrated? Is that correct? Maybe that's not a great example, I just happened to notice the question today as it was my first time on security.se

Comment: The big one was the sci-fi question

Comment: Programmers Stack Exchange is not a "trilogy site".

Comment: @PeterO. - I know, but still pretty damn big, compared to ours. I was just lumping the big ones in together.

Comment: This is a great point.  The defense for allowing users to vote on the question on both sites was "separate sites are separate" which, joined with this, seems to indicate it doesn't make sense to keep the vote count from the original site.