# Is a question asking for an algorithm to sort socks into pairs on-topic?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, specific-question, off-topic

[How to pair socks from a pile efficiently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14415881/how-to-pair-socks-from-a-pile-efficiently) asks for an algorithm for sorting socks into pairs. On what basis is this on-topic for SO?

Should it not be migrated to Programmers, [Computer Science](https://cs.stackexchange.com/) or [Theoretical Computer Science](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/)?

It asks for an algorithm with a certain efficiency.

---

Update : The OP has mentioned that he just wants a **theoretical answer** with an efficiency beating `nlogn` and not a *practical solution*. So, that "practical real-world question" is asking for an answer that may not necessarily be implementable.

Comment: Questions aren't off topic on SO just because they might be on topic on another site.

Comment: Not to mention that you really can't migrate it at this point. It has so many votes that it'll be fairly disruptive to the CSTheory community.

Comment: Since when is sorting a pile of socks research-level computer science? :p

Comment: It would become the most highly upvoted question on CS or CSTheory if migrated, so it definitely shouldn't be migrated now.

Comment: @ThiefMaster, the government will give you money for the craziest kind of research these days.

Comment: I'm blown away by the fact the question is one day old and got that many votes.

Comment: @LanceRoberts It's on the front page of http://www.reddit.com/r/programming

Comment: @BilltheLizard, ah, that explains it all, thanks.

Comment: The question is on topic on Stack Overflow, Programmers and Computer Science. It's rare, but it happens, and when it happens it's almost always a great question. For the record, I tried stealing it for Programmers but @casperOne wouldn't let me.

Comment: That question is about to get auto-wikied from having too many answers. That said, I think some of the answers can be purged.

Comment: WTF is with that question getting so many votes...

Comment: @nhahtdh It's a question about socks, so the votes are probably from sockpuppets /paranoia

Comment: @Yannis Did you just say that something is on-topic for the Programmers SE? What on earth is going on?

Comment: @Bart I even [re-opened a question](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/7750340#7750340) last night. There's only one explanation, [tequila](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/7750405#7750405). ;P

Comment: Seriously? The obscene number of Reddit-driven upvotes (and joke answers) aside, it's a _relief_ to see a thoughtful, well-written question that requires some expertise and brainpower like this on SO. If this is a candidate for closure, then SO isn't worth much any more.

Comment: @JoshCaswell It's a good question, sure, but that doesn't make it on-topic.

Comment: @BilltheLizard I love the notice "Welcome, Redditors! We're looking for answers that provide serious, practical solutions to the problem stated. If you'd prefer to post a joke or launch a tangential discussion, please do so on the corresponding Reddit thread.". Is that added automatically somehow?

Comment: @Andrew: no, I just threw that on there to see if a bit of polite advice could avoid us having to lock it.

Comment: _Really_ good call, @Shog9.

Comment: @BilltheLizard If it's a legitimate question that's been legitimately up-voted, why shouldn't it be migrated somewhere that it would be on-topic and in accordance with a site's FAQ? Why should the vote count matter?

Comment: @CodeGnome: Historically, famous and hyper-high-scored questions have been allowed to evade the site's content rules/guidelines. I, like you, disagree with this pattern, though I can't see it changing any day soon.

Comment: @nhahtdh: It got [Reddit](http://www.reddit.com)ed.

Comment: +1 not because I agree with this meta question, but for alerting me to the SO question!

Comment: First comment: "NO, DON'T MIGRATE IT TO PROGRAMMERS! ***NOOOOOOO!!!!***" by who else but @Yannis.

Comment: I ran out of votes for the day downvoting the answers there...I mean seriously. Such a bad joke too... Worse, you know the question asker had no intent other than rep whoring when they protected their own question.

Comment: @ThiefMaster sorting a pile of socks is research-level computer science *by definition* whenever and as soon as anyone asks for a research-level computer science solution to it.

Comment: Even if it's a research-level computer science question, it doesn't mean it has any connection with software development / programming, or is actually on topic for SO. If all of these questions were on-topic for SO, why would things like cs.stackexchange need to exist?

Comment: I found some great real-world examples for programming concepts in that question and it's answers. But it's a shame the [2nd highest voted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14419496/302677) containing algorithms such as the "Mom algorithm" got deleted, although I guess I can see how it could be guiding answers towards "joke" answers because of the way it was written :)

Answer (score 13):

It comes down to this: **either** the question is off-topic, **or** the FAQ is wrong/unclear/incomplete.

Either way there is something to fix.

Comment: No need for Off Topic, because it certainly meets the definition of Not Constructive.

Comment: It's still open, what has the world become. Or, the FAQ is still wrong,  what has the world become.

Answer (score 8):

Algorithm questions are fine for Stack Overflow, even if they also fit on another site.  That question is tagged appropriately: [algorithm](/questions/tagged/algorithm), [sorting](/questions/tagged/sorting) and definitely [language-agnostic](/questions/tagged/language-agnostic).

Comment: Some [tag:language-agnostic] questions related to [tag:sorting] [tag:algorithm] are on-topic, but not this one: it is not about a “software algorithm”, it isn't related to programming, any more than “how do I install Windows” is related to programming even if you're asking how to set up a machine that will be used by a developer.

Comment: "[Don't ask a]nything not directly related to writing computer programs" is clearly spelled out on the [About page](http://stackoverflow.com/about). Algorithms can certainly be on-topic, but the question *as a whole* does not qualify.

Comment: I have to −1 because this is a tad too simplistic. What you're saying right now is that if I ask on SO for a recipe for a really tasty egg-salad sandwich, it will be perfectly on-topic as long as I tag it [algorithm] and [language-agnostic].

Comment: As long as it meets the other criteria of the site.

Comment: If you ask how to make that egg-salad sandwich algorithmically through language-agnostic computer programming, it's on topic and correctly tagged.

Answer (score 8):

#### TL; DR

[The question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14415881/how-to-pair-socks-from-a-pile-efficiently) is not about a practical programming question that the author is facing. The most generous interpretation is that it is an abstract math problem without a concrete programming task to address.

#### Problems With This Question

1. "What is the best way..." questions are usually polling questions,
   or questions that lead to extended debates about the definition of
   "best."
2. It is not about a specific *programming* problem.
3. It is not about a *software* algorithm.
4. It is not about software *tools* commonly used by programmers.
5. It is not a *practical*, answerable problem unique to the programming profession.
6. It *smells* like a "g1v3 m3 d4 c0d3z" question.

At best, this is a brain teaser or an abstract math question, rather than a programming problem in search of a solution. It could certainly be edited or re-framed to be on-topic, but that would most likely ruin the original authorial intent.

None of this means it isn't well-written, or engaging. Clearly, many people think it's a fun or interesting question, and are up-voting it accordingly. However, popularity doesn't intrinsically make it on-topic.

#### What To Do About It

Perhaps there's a place elsewhere on Stack Exchange for it. Sadly, unless the question is rewritten as a programming question, it just doesn't belong here.

Comment: Can't say I completely agree here: 1) "How to" != "What's the best" 2) OP is looking for a programmic way to solve it. 3) OP is looking to do it with software. 4) True, but it doesn't need to be. 5) How is a pair matching algorithm not practical? 6) Kinda true. I'll give this one to you.

Comment: @Mysticial I appreciate the thoughtful response, but: 1) "what is the best way to pair them up efficiently with up to logarithmic extra space?" is an exact quote from the question; 2) OP specifically asks for a "general theoretical solution for a huge number of socks"; 3) OP doesn't mention "anything directly related to writing computer programs" (see http://stackoverflow.com/about). It's easy to get side-tracked by the fact that it's algorithmic, but it does *not* meet the criteria listed in our FAQ or About pages.

Comment: 1) That seems a bit more like nitpicking. 2) I don't see anything particularly bad about a general algorithm? He's asking for a general algorithm to a *specific* problem. 3) Under that argument, we might as well start by closing every single question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/algorithm).

Comment: The FAQ, although it's been tightened up considerably over the years, does allow some leeway for things like this. He faced a real problem (one that many of us have), and is asking for a programmatic solution to it (naturally, one would have to assume the presence of some rather specialized hardware in order to actually *implement* it). That said, I appreciate this can be a bit of a stretch, so: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164436/is-curiosity-an-actual-problem-to-be-solved

Comment: @Shog9 are you seriously expecting him to start hashing his socks from  tomorrow ?

Comment: @Shog9 also, who decides how much of a *stretch* is allowed ? The opinion here suggests that is in fact **off-topic** however borderline it may be

Comment: @Shog9: amit is free to start a blog and put his sock curiosity on there...

Answer (score 2):

I agree that the question is off-topic. It is not about programming.

The question cannot be migrated to [Computer Science](https://cs.stackexchange.com/) (where it would be squarely on-topic), because it has had far too many votes. [Migration retains the votes from the source site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87031/reset-votes-on-migrated-questions), which here would be highly disproportionate: there would be no way for the target community to rate the answers. The question cannot be migrated to [Theoretical Computer Science](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/) because it is off-topic there (it is not a research-level question). I'm not familiar enough with [Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) to comment.

However, this is a good question that has had good answers, and while it is off-topic, it is close to the border: algorithms are strongly related to programming. So I am disinclined to close it. If I had seen it when it was initially posted, I would have voted to close it as off-topic, and requested a migration to [Computer Science](https://cs.stackexchange.com/).

This is a case if there ever was one for adding a [post notice](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126587/what-is-a-historical-lock-and-what-is-it-used-for) (without the lock: there's no reason to prevent edits, votes or further answers) to indicate that this question is off-topic but kept around for historical reasons.

Comment: I'm pretty certain algorithms have never been *off-topic* on Stack Overflow. Ever. There are certainly other sites where there's considerably more focus on them, but that's irrelevant.

Comment: @Shog9, Who makes those decisions?  Isn't it just left up to close/reopen votes and mods, case-by-case? For example, [here's one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6027048/anyone-name-this-algorithm)...

Comment: [Here's 24 thousand others](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Balgorithm%5D+closed%3A0)

Comment: @TheCommunity: You're right, that should probably be "too localized: even if anyone is wondering the same thing, they'll never be able to find this question".

Comment: Those are just closed, not closed as off-topic.

Comment: Look closer, @The.

Comment: Ehh, open, whatever ;)

Comment: @Gilles: While you're right that "good" does not equal "on-topic", the question at hand is not about programming the same way a question about rubber-sheet gravity is not about astronomy.

Comment: @Shog9: Oh my dear...[that tag is](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572640/interview-question-find-median-from-mega-number-of-integers) [a](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3643524/who-can-i-turn-to-for-analysis-of-my-algorithm) [close-vote](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2779747/algorithm-for-a-dice-problem) [sinkhole](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2799107/recursive-code-sorting-in-vb)...

Comment: A post notice without the lock would be a pretty good feature request, imo, for one-off questions like this that may not be good examples of what's on topic.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some excerpts from the FAQ. Italicized comments are mine.

---

**What kind of questions can I ask here?**

> - a specific programming problem

*Nope, this isn't one.*

> - a software algorithm

*Nope, it asks for an algorithm, but nowhere in the question is it applied to software.*

> - software tools commonly used by programmers

*Nope, just socks.*

> - practical, answerable problems that are unique to the programming profession

*Nope, impractical and not unique to programming.*

---

**What kind of questions should I *not* ask here?**

> You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face.

*Again, impractical. Just sort your socks.*

> Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page.

*IMO this question fits the bill to a tee.*

> If your motivation for asking the question is “I would like to participate in a discussion about ______”, then you should not be asking here.

*Sure looks like that's what's going on here. Many of the answers and comments are just attempts at humor, and are not really useful.*

---

I'd think most people would be able to find something here to refute the legitimacy of this question if they wanted to badly enough.

Comment: In elementary school, maths is often taught with examples such as "Alice has 6 apples and she gives 2 each to Bob and Charlie. How many does she have left?". The idea is not to teach kids about apples or socialism, but to make the boring (for a 6 yr old) subject of addition/subtraction "fun" and "interesting". The socks here is just that — a little tale that allows everyone to personally relate to an otherwise dry question on algorithms. If you can't cut through the story to get to the point, then I suggest that you refrain from voting to close something that you know little about.

Comment: The part where you're wrong is "software algorithm"; the interpretation that's most commonly used is "algorithms that are used in software", not "algorithms that specifically deal with software".

Comment: In other news, "Alice & Bob" stories are *not* actually soap operas.

Comment: Alright, so if you want to treat this as a serious question instead of a sort of joke conversation, is it not simply a duplicate of, say, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4259890/sorting-algorithm)?

Comment: «`*a specific programming problem` _Nope, this isn't one._ `*a software algorithm`
_Nope, it's an algorithm, but not applied to software._ » Are you kidding? You can't handle a simple analogy?

Comment: I can handle an analogy. I have a low tolerance for high-volume blatant trolling. And as I said, if you want to take it seriously, fine, let's close it as a duplicate.

Comment: The "trolling" is being handled as it comes in; there's a dozen deleted joke answers attached to the question (and you can contribute to comment cleanup, if you wish, by flagging). That will die down as the Reddit interest fades. I don't see any evidence of trolling on the part of the asker; e seems to be encouraging quality answers in comments. The duplicate you've suggested is a ***terrible*** question. It is related only in that it also falls under the topic of "sorting".

Comment: This is also a terrible question, I thought it was quite fitting. It is vague, it begs for discussion, and without having the slightest clue how it's supposed to be applied to actual software, it's impractical to try to answer it in a useful way.

Comment: I will concede that it's broad, but you have a very strange definition of "vague". «Given a pile of n pairs of socks, containing 2n elements (assume each sock has exactly one matching pair), what is the best way to pair them up efficiently with up to logarithmic extra space?» seems specific enough to me. And if you can't see how this could be applied to a programming problem, then I repeat my question about simple analogies.

Comment: It's vague because it's *just* an analogy that never ties in to reality, so you get all kinds of answers that just have an analogy to go on... so now we're monogramming socks and dying them different colors and so on, and at this point it's unclear how the extended analogy actually ties back in to software development. If it wasn't vague, [this guy](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14419228/886931) could have given one answer instead of three.

Comment: Does every correspondence really need to be spelled out explicitly? Monogramming/dying socks: add a pre-computed hash field to the data structure you're interested in sorting to speed up your comparisons.

Comment: It's also a question of whether the socks are already monogrammed/colored/whatever. Do they have distinguishable features? Does it matter if we pair a sock with a look-alike that is not actually its mate? How much space do we have available to make piles of socks? But yes, also, are we allowed to mark the socks, or will the wife yell at us? The question is silly.

Comment: «Do they have distinguishable features? Does it matter if we pair a sock with a look-alike...» _How does our comparison function define equality?_ «How much space do we have available to make piles of socks?» This is already part of the question: _"...with up to logarithmic extra space"_. «are we allowed to mark the socks, or will the wife yell at us?» _Is the data structure even under our control, or does it, e.g., come from a web API so that we have to_ k̶e̶e̶p̶ ̶a̶ ̶l̶i̶s̶t̶ ̶o̶n̶ ̶a̶ ̶n̶o̶t̶e̶p̶a̶d̶ _store our hashes somewhere else._ Use your imagination a little here.

Comment: Josh Caswell, right... we likely wouldn't have to ask those questions if this were an actual software development question. Missed the part where the extra space question was handled though, good catch.

Comment: Those aren't questions about the question, they're questions that the answers need to address, hopefully in depth. Have you read [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/)? It's got good stuff to say about judging questions like this.

Comment: "Does it matter if we pair a sock with a look-alike that is not actually its mate?" — You are being intentionally dense here... The question is very clear when it says: "**assume each sock has exactly one matching pair**" Given this, `pair(a, b)` is a Boolean function and there is no ambiguity as to what should be done with a look-alike.

Comment: @AnonE.Mouse You're right, I take it back, he did cover that. I'm still not at all sure what would be done with look-alikes, though. I have tons of socks that all look alike, how will I find their one-and-only? If there are no look-alikes and each pair is visually distinct (holds a visual reference its mate), why do we need an algorithm at all? Just ask the sock who its mate is / spread them all out and look at them / whatever fits the analogy.