# Should do-my-homework questions be closed as "Not a Real Question" or "Too localized"?

Tags: discussion, questions, vote-to-close, close-reasons, homework

My question is pretty much in the title. We all know that there are a lot of questions that simply copy-paste their homework assignment text without showing any effort. [This recent one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15710602/c-sharp-binary-search#comment22313004_15710602), for example. I clicked on Close and there was one "Not a real question" close vote, but I chose "Too localized". Which one is recommended in such cases?

Comment: Related: [Do "fix my code pleeese!" questions qualify for closure as "too localized"?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/82874)

Answer (score 7):

They should be closed as "Not a real question".

"Too localized", which I discovered today from [this thread](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/174165/148949):

> Too Localized is a question that cannot help anyone else ever again - quite possibly including the person who asked it. It definitely does not mean "unlikely to help the person reading it with close-vote in hand".

and [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/133574/148949):

> Everything is localized in some way, but if your problem is so localized, so specific to this place, this time, those people... that even if it is answered, the answer will never again help anyone else...
>   That's Too Localized.

indicate that "Too localized" should not be used for homework questions.  Typos fall under the category of "too localized", since once the typo is corrected, the original poster won't even need it again; homework falls under "not a real question", since no effort was put into the question.

Also see [What questions should be closed with reason "too localized"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4818/what-questions-should-be-closed-with-reason-too-localized)

Comment: I disagree with your interpretation... The answer to a specific homework question *is* going to be "too localized" because the only person it will help is the person with that assignment. It is unlikely to ever be useful to anyone else in the future. (Unless you're counting on everyone enrolled in the class being on SO?) It's not a big deal, though: either close reason satisfy me just as well.

Comment: Actually it will help everyone who have similar homework assignment.

Comment: @CodyGray - that's a valid point, although I *have* seen multiple users from the same class all find SO at the same time.  I never really used "Too Localized" until the Typo Cleanup earlier this year.  But I agree; closed is closed is closed.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if it would be possible to have additional option to be added: "Homework"

Comment: But being homework is not in itself a valid and sufficient reason to close.

Comment: Homework is something that user should be able to work out itself, not get solution handed to him on plate.

Comment: As covered in [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/123763/145673) there are many bad homework questions that already can be closed for existing close reasons. Certainly it is possible for someone to have a good question relating to homework though and I wouldn't like to see those closed just because someone happened to mention that it was homework related. A homework close reason seems unnecessary to me and (like the homework tag) would probably be applied inappropriately even when the OP themselves didn't state that it was homework.

Comment: IMO not *all* homework questions require closure.  I'm sure there are quite a few good ones; where the student searches, tries, and then asks a question with his current code, what he has tried, etc.

Comment: That's another thing - I agree that not all need to be closed if the question is advanced. But if someone asks: "How to create an array and multiple it's members by 10" then I would like to close it with Homework option.

Comment: But what difference does it make if they ask that question as part of completing a homework assignment or a hobby project or as part of their job? If it is a bad question the existing close reasons should cover it. The motivation of the asker is irrelevant. There isn't a "too basic" close reason though.