# Why is this answer flag rejected, moderators don't need help?

Tags: discussion, new-users, low-quality-posts, declined-flags, not-an-answer

I flagged this answer as "not an answer":

[Load .txt File to GridControl (DevExpress)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19063945/load-txt-file-to-gridcontrol-devexpress/19113705#19113705)

For the users who cannot see the content of the linked answer:

"Sorry for the late answer , I've found another way for this . as you said , using DataSource but What I would like to know now , is how to Load in it from SQL Server Database"

Surely this is a comment to the other answer, but my flag was rejected, and I don't know why?

Sure at least one of moderators believes that it's not an answer to the question, because they deleted this answer ([Shog9](https://stackoverflow.com/users/811/shog9)). Surely this kind of rejection (which happens sometimes) disappoints users. And a next time someone like me is not going to flag such things (as "not an answer").

Maybe some moderators are accepting and rejecting flags in a bulk manner, but when someone flags as "not an answer", they should read the question and answer carefully, and if they cannot understand they should leave it to other moderators, instead of bulk accepting or rejecting. (This particular answer is very clearly a comment to the other answer and the user couldn't leave a comment  because of low reputation, and provided it as an answer, in this case a moderator checked it in blind manner).

My previous [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194328/how-is-this-answer-programming-related) was about not an answer, answers and moderator rejection, which means this pattern is usual.

Comment: If there are many flags it is impossible to accept/reject them together.  So if there was an incorrect flag in amongst them they must all be rejected

Comment: Also, it really looks like its going to be a (really bad) answer ("ive found annother way") before it tails off into a question

Comment: @MartijnPieters, That question mostely focuses on quality, but I'm talking about obvious not an answer, answer, with specific sample.

Comment: @RichardTingle, What you mentioned is blind reading of answer, everyone can add "This is an answer to the question", and ask a question instead of answering, if moderator don't read it carefully, he thinks this is an answer. Because of this I added extra part to explain why moderator should not judge about such a flag if they cannot distinguish it.

Comment: @Saeed: my apologies; I looked at a wrong window; that is an obvious non-answer. Possibly it was flagged with an incorrect flag, in which case *all* flags end up dismissed.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, OK, thanks. I didn't know this case then. You can provide it as answer, and after I see there is no other reason, I'll accept it.

Comment: @Saeed: We're not that stupid. If someone has to state in their answer whether it is an answer or not, chances are it's not actually an answer.

Comment: FWIW it looks like a different moderator declined the first batch of flags before it was reflagged again and deleted. I wasn't involved with this answer in either way though so I shan't comment further.

Comment: @Saeed, Moderators are human too and they can make mistake, but just making one mistake does not mean that they don't need help or they are always checking in "blind manner". For flagging, I use "not an answer" flag mostly and I have not faced any case where the flag is declined wrongly. So I won't say that this pattern is "usual".

Comment: I have flagged many posts in the past and found that out of around 100 NAA flags, 99 were accepted (one was declined but that was because I had used the wrong option). So generalizing things is not correct. In case of answer look-alikes, you can also consider using the "other" (custom) option and explain further the reason for flagging. After all, mods are also human.

Comment: @Harry, By this question and its comments I understand the "other", is better option. But my case is not like yours, I see more than two time rejection, and I believe they were correct (I flagged less than 20 as NNA).

Comment: I had a short discussion with one of the mods (when the one flag stated in my previous comment was declined) and based on that what I believe is that a 2nd flag on the same post is/will be treated more carefully (though I don't know how mods track it). However, in my opinion, when a NAA flag is declined it just means that another person looking at the post has interpreted it differently. So, the 2nd time raise it as other and explain your POV.

Comment: @Saeed Thanks for bringing this up. It is very important that moderators correctly handle flags. In this case though, it was completely a mistake. As Anders UP already answered, I just made too quick of a judgement on this flag. I will be more careful in the future.

Comment: @jjnguy, Good job, Thanks for your responsibility. I know that moderators are busy. Also I check my question/answer/flags, sometimes, and I see this maybe late. But I see is useful to mention it, at least I learned using *other* flag is better.

Comment: @Saeed you are welcome. Glad you are keeping an eye on things!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is in essence multiple questions in one. First part of the title says "Why is this [Not an] answer flag rejected".

That part of your question is an exact duplicate, as I flagged the exact same answer and got it declined, which I raised in [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/199451/declined-naa-flag) question. The involved mod [responded](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/199475/213634) fairly quickly:

> This was completely my mistake.

So that was a simple error that was easily corrected as the flagged answer is now deleted.

In this question, you refer to [your previous question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/194328/213634) and suggest that a pattern of wrongful declines exist. While I [share](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/199456/213634) some of the concerns you have, in my view mostly that the `NAA`-flag is too simple and frequently requires further explanation, I disagree that you can box

> Sorry for the late answer , I've found another way for this . as you said , using DataSource but What I would like to know now , is how to Load in it from SQL Server Database

together with

> According to a recent episode of Radiolab (about "Falling"), a cat reaches terminal velocity by the 9th floor. After that, it relaxes and is less likely to be hurt. There are completely uninjured cats after a fall from above the 30th. The riskiest floors are 5th to 9th.

and then claim that they should be treated similarly. These answers are fundamentally different and cannot be used together to form a pattern in moderator behaviour when declining `NAA`.

If you look at the answers to [my broader question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/199456/213634), you can see that the mods are actually divided on what they prefer, so the line is not 100% clear.

My takeaway is that `NAAs` are handled in bulk, so if it is not immediately visible *why* something is Not An Answer, it should be flagged as `Other`with an explanation of why. I personally still think that your previous example would be declined, even with a longer explanation.

Finally, the last part of your title reads "moderators don't need help?". I think they do. That's why they hold elections to fill the ranks from time to time - and probably also why they rely heavily on the rest of the community to bring proper issues to their attention.

Comment: In my opinion all of this stuffs are pattern for blind reading, I expecting to see this from moderators, because they can do mistake like any other human, but not very often, and seems to be more than usual mistake, and one reason may be is number of active moderators is not enough to manage all the flags, or they should allow some active users to handle this. There are some comments that answers my question in some way (like different flags for one answer or the comment that says moderator can make a mistake), but to be honest your answer to me seems, does not answer my question in any sense.

Comment: @Saeed I was editing my answer heavily while you wrote this comment.

Comment: Ok I'll read your updated answer later. but note that my question was in proposal format. and is not same as your question.

Comment: @Saeed Yes, I realized that you had more points in your question, that was why I updated my answer.

Comment: I'm not agree with your argument about the pattern, it would be nice if you disagree with my other question provide a comment or answer there, but by the positive upvote and downvote counts on the answer, means people are mostly agree that is not an answer. But your current answer, answers my question in some sense, if there is no other better answer (later) I'll accept it.

Comment: @Saeed I do agree, partly, with your other question and I actually upvoted it some time ago, but I still disagree that the answer discussed there and the answer discussed here are in any way related. I'll go through your other question again and leave a comment if I feel I can add something new to it.

Comment: @AndersUP thanks for responding!