# Should we migrate this old, highly upvoted question to Super User?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, specific-question, migration, off-topic

I just saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/112396/how-do-i-remove-the-passphrase-for-the-ssh-key-without-having-to-create-a-new-ke) question. It has a high score and a very high score answer, so it's been useful to many people.

This question got closed as off topic. I don't know if I agree with that, but even if it is off topic, why not migrate it to Super User?

I'm not familiar with the migration process, I'd appreciate your opinion on the subject and relevant explanations.

Comment: If you think the question should be migrated to [SU] then you can flag the question for moderator's attention and explain the same in *Others* flag reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like [hims056 says](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190275/migrate-a-specific-question#comment589339_190275), if you think a specific, closed question deserves migration to another site, you will have to solicit the help of a moderator. Do that by flagging the question, clicking the "other" option, and explaining your rationale in the text box provided.

But do keep in mind that moderators will probably not migrate this question for two reasons:

1. It's *quite* old, hailing from the early days of Stack Overflow way back in 2008. As a rule, we don't migrate old questions to other sites.
2. Like you point out, it has accumulated *a lot* of votes. [Positive votes are not (currently) cleared when questions are migrated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87031/reset-votes-on-migrated-questions), so this would be a huge "shock" to the Super User community.

The best time to migrate a question is *early*, when it is first asked, ideally before it has even accumulated any answers. We missed that on this question, precisely because of its age and the shifting definition of which topics are on topic for Stack Overflow.

Even *moderators* cannot migrate old questions. There is a 60-day age restriction that is technically enforced.

Fundamentally, while I agree with you that this is a good question, would have fit well on Super User were it originally asked there, and that it is and will probably be useful to a lot of people, I don't see a good reason why it needs to be migrated at this point. It already has an answer, and its information continues to be available to those who are looking for it. I would be very much again *deleting* this question, but it should remain closed as it is not on topic for Stack Overflow. SSH keys are no more specific to programming than installing an operating system.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Can you elaborate about the shock to the SU community? 
I just think it's a shame to keep such a good question in a closed state, so no newer contributions can be made, if there are any.

Comment: @Noich Basically, various circumstances have caused the question to accumulate a lot more votes on Stack Overflow than it is likely to have received "organically" on Super User. And if the answers to that question ever become obsolete and new contributions need to be made, it should be *re-asked* on Super User and the obsolete original deleted.

Comment: As a matter of fact, we *cannot* migrate old questions. There's a 60-day restriction that's technically enforced.

Comment: @Bolt Oh, I assumed moderators were not subject to that restriction. You guys were just trusted not to do something stupid.

Comment: Quite the contrary, we have to compile a list of questions to be migrated, on meta—the community team won't accept a single question for migration, even if both sites wanted it.

Comment: If you find an old, blatantly off-topic question that would be a valuable addition to another site, don't hesitate to ask one of us for a migration, @slhck. What we're trying to avoid are mass-migrations of *on-topic* questions to other sites where they also happen to be on-topic. Because this happened. A *lot*. And it just ended up annoying people.

Comment: @Shog9 I remember the last time I wanted a highly popular (but closed, off topic) FFmpeg question migrated from SO to SU, I was told that it wasn't possible and I should only ask if I have a list…

Comment: Hmm... No, that's not right. Sorry, @slhck - should've made this more clear in the past.