# How to deal with old questions that are off-topic and cannot be migrated?

Tags: discussion, migration, off-topic

I was looking for a possible duplicated question about [another question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/84669/41104) in [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com), then looked using the Big G! since the integrated search didn't give me any useful result (*laugs*) then I found the [perfect answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4056912/792066), but in Stackoverflow! Then, I proceed to flag as off-topic, but since "It's too old to migrate" I don't have the option to do so...

So, my question is, should I leave it like that? Or the question is better in UL (also on topic, just read the question)? Any guidance to this young *pada-wan* is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sorta-kinda-almost a duplicate of: [Should we migrate this old, highly upvoted question to Super User?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/190275)/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just vote to close, the mods don't have any tools to solve the situation any better than community close votes would. Leaving a comment with the other two sites that are more appropriate is a good idea as well.

<s>I'm not sure what tools the mods have for this situation, but faced with a similar situation, I would flag "it needs ♦ moderator attention" -> "other" and put your thoughts about migrating it there.</s>

Even if they don't have the tools to migrate it somehow, I'd think they can close it with some sort of explanatory note pointing to the better site for that kind of question.

Comment: Moderators can't migrate it either. If it's blatantly off-topic, it'd just get closed. Otherwise nothing would probably happen.

Comment: I suspected that might be the case - can the mods at least signpost the site where it belongs when they close it?

Comment: Signpost? We can leave a comment, but then again, so can you.

Comment: Not knowing the tools, it appears as if certain questions closed by mods have custom messages in the close reason box?

Comment: We can't customize that on-the-fly. There are certain options that anyone with vote-to-close privileges can choose from, and entering something in the other box just closes it as off-topic in general and adds a comment.

Comment: Gotcha. In that case, changing my answer, because if there's nothing else to be done, I'd just vote to close.

Comment: Ok, voted with a custom reason, and leave the link to this question it is, so ♦ can know what is being done here.

Comment: Great, I've made people waste flags :/ http://i.stack.imgur.com/idOEh.png

Answer (score 3):

In addition to voting/flagging to close, you can and should also **post the question and answer yourself** on the appropriate site.  Feel free to credit the original poster and/or post in the answer.  Having the appropriate knowledge on the appropriate site is just as important, if not more, than removing off-topic questions.

Comment: Done that too :D. Now give me a cookie!

Comment: Cookie given.  :)