# Why is this question better suited for DBA than SO?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, specific-question, migration, database

I've asked [this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/51430/is-using-distinct-as-a-hint-in-subqueries-useful) two days ago.

The question deals with a simple subquery and when to use a `DISTINCT` operation.

In my opinion, this is a thing a programmer that works with relational databases (and surely an enthusiast) should know.

The question was migrated to [database administrators](https://dba.stackexchange.com/). Why?

Comment: Why do you care?  It got an incredibly useful answer on DBA.

Comment: This answer was received in SO.

Comment: @RobertHarvey to be fair, it already had that answer before it was migrated. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as why it's "better suited", I think it's pretty clear. It's on topic for both sites, but a bit *more* so on DBA.

I get the feeling the real motivation for your question is because it's annoying to have your post migrated to some SE site that you aren't too interested in, with a smaller user base, where questions take way longer to get answered and less people see them.

Personally I would have preferred the question be left where it was if it was mine, but to me this is the best of both worlds. You got a timely accepted answer on SO, and now the post can help others on the more specific site, and as a bonus a little awareness was raised of dba.stackexchange.com.

Your question seemed to be more of a curiosity than an urgent issue, so in that respect if I were to ask it again, I would ask at DBA where you can possibly get a more qualified, thought out answer rather than a "quick and dirty" one (typical SO answer).

Comment: Also, aside, this I don't like, votes from SO can skew perception on smaller sites: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87031/reset-votes-on-migrated-questions

Answer (score 7):

Because 5 pretty smart users of both sites thought it would be more relevant and valuable on the database administrators site. Just because a database-related question is on-topic on Stack Overflow does not make it off-topic everywhere else, nor does it necessarily make Stack Overflow the *best* place for it. Stack Overflow database-related questions tend to be simple things like "how do I get the just-inserted identity value?" and endless streams of "how do I split a comma-separated value?" The topic of the question, and even more so the details in Mikael's answer, make it a question that is more complex than average. Don't you want it on the site where it can get the best answers, rather than remain on the site where you asked? I'm not sure I understand why it matters which site it's on as long as you received a satisfactory answer.

https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: I know the guidelines, but I'm still not sure about how complex issue it really is for a non DBA programmer. and if I's really on topic and got relevant attention and answers in SO, why migrating it.I see your point tough. And one more thing, it doesn't matter for this question, but for future note.

Comment: @Yosi the nice thing about this community is that you don't have to know in advance. You might have absolutely no idea how complex your question really is, but other users (like those who voted to migrate this question) can help guide you to the place where you're most likely to get the best help.

Answer (score 2):

Quoting the DBA Help section:

> If you have a question about...

...

> **Advanced Querying including
> window-functions, dynamic-sql, and query-performance**

...

> but, dba.se is *not* the right place to ask questions about...
>
> Client-side programming - ask on Stack Overflow
>
> **Basic SQL - ask on Stack Overflow**

Emphasis mine. From what I can tell, your question can be considered advanced querying, not basic SQL.

Comment: When a question is on-topic for multiple sites, isn't the policy to leave it on the site it was asked?

Comment: @WesleyMurch: Sometimes. I think that when it comes to migrating from SO to other sites though, I think that questions will usually be migrated for the good of the other site.

Comment: I guess the question "Why is this question better suited for DBA than SO?" is not strictly the same as "Why was it migrated?".

Comment: @Wesley well, the latter can certainly be answered by the former, can't it?

Comment: @AaronBertrand Pretty much. Assuming we always migrate a question purely on the basis that it's better suited elsewhere, and how we define "better suited".

Comment: @WesleyMurch well, like up-votes, down-votes, and many other things, there is no formal definition for "better suited" - that is up to each person with the ability to cast a vote.