# When to move my question from DBA to Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

I've seen some older questions about when to post on the DBA vs. Stack Overflow and there seems to be no rhyme or reason to place one place vs the other for basic SQL/DB questions.

I put a bounty on a question on dba last week(started 2 weeks ago) and it got no answers.

I asked a question yesterday and have received no comments or answers. Looking at the usage on DBA it also seems to be less active than SO.

I don't want to use the last of my rep on another bounty that will go unanswered. At what point should I migrate my question to SO? Are there some more specific guidelines for when to post at DBA over SO?

The current question I'm wondering about is, https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/139289/get-the-query-that-caused-the-trigger-to-execute.

Comment: Rather than adding more bounties or moving a question to a less-appropriate site, a link to your post may help folks explain how your question(s) can be improved, or at least how to increase your chances of getting a favorable response.

Comment: This one: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/137809/why-does-score-for-mysql-boolean-match-give-different-score ?

Comment: @Catija that is the one I bountied, that wasn't my question but I was interested in its result. I've added a link to my question here.

Comment: Closely related/inverse: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/201695/why-is-this-question-better-suited-for-dba-than-so

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some questions fit on both sites, and so it this question of yours. At what point you migrate is up to you. You can even delete this question and post it on Stack Overflow yourself. No need for moderation attention here.

In deciding on which SE site to post, you might want to take a closer look on what is really on-topic on both sites and see if the question better fits site A or B. Also look into the tags you are planning to use: how active are the members there? How many questions are asked on similar subjects? That will help you to decide which site to ask your question on.

Comment: Thanks, I've moved it to Stack and will see how that turns out.

Comment: Yup, looks like posting on SO was the answer, 5 hours after posting issue resolved.

Comment: Great! Good luck with the answer.