# Reposting a Deleted Question (I deleted my profile in the meanwhile)

Tags: discussion, deleted-accounts, reposts

I asked a question on the Electrical Engineering site regarding RSSI variations. I then flagged it for migration to Physics site since it seemed more relevant there. I deleted it after a few days since I thought I should do more research and then ask a more specific question. Consequently, I also deleted my Physics profile since I thought I would no longer use it again.

I now want to re post the same question since I have bonus reputation and can offer a bounty on it. I know I shouldn't have been so hasty with everything but here is a copy of the question I deleted. Would re posting it on Physics site be frowned upon?

---

> I am doing some experiments to measure [Received Signal Strength
>   Indicator
>   (RSSI)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Received_signal_strength_indication)
>   variations of a TX/RX pair of CC1120 modules when a person passes in
>   between them. I constantly fire packets and measure RSSI.
>
> I have mounted a Pulse W5017 antenna on both of them and it's facing
>   vertically upwards on both nodes. The data sheet of this antenna can
>   be found here:
>
> http://productfinder.pulseeng.com/product/W5017
>
> After experimentation, I found out that when the nodes are placed on
>   the ground, a breach between the nodes (a person passing between)
>   creates a MUCH better dip in RSSI as compared to when the nodes are
>   placed on a height, such as a workbench. See the graphs below:
>
> [image: Floor] [image: Bench]
>
> **The experiment was repeated to confirm the above observation.**
>
> The radiation patterns of the antennas are as shown below (from the
>   datasheet):
>
> [image: Radiation Pattern]
>
> By using the datasheet, and seeing the vertical pattern (since I am
>   studying the effective height of placing the nodes), how does the
>   observation match with the vertical radiation pattern? Before looking
>   at the pattern, I had something of the following sort in mind:
>
> [image: Bench] [image]
>
> A 3D view of the radiation pattern from both horizontal and vertical
>   planes can be visualized as below:
>
> [image: Radiation Pattern in 3D]
>
> Does it have something to do with the fact that when the nodes are
>   placed on the ground, the lower lobe goes beneath the ground? Is it
>   reflected above? What happens to the lower lobe?

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you are using the processes available to you as they were intended.

When you have a question that potentially could fit on multiple sites, you start by picking the site you feel is the *best* fit and post your question there. **Cross-posting to multiple sites is not allowed.**

If, after some reasonable period of time, you don't get the answer you were hoping for, you are free to ask a similar question on another site. The question should be tailored to the subject and posting conventions of the new site and not simply cut-and-paste'd indiscriminately.

Migrating the post directly wasn't really appropriate in your situation. **Migration is intended to preserve useful content,** so when a question has no answers, migrating a post where the user(s) may not have an account on the other site causes too many side effects simply to save a little typing. It is better to have the author ask the question themselves, posted within the context of the other site.

If you feel the question on the *original* site is not being well received or isn't otherwise helpful, you are free to delete it. **I would avoid posting a question and deleting it *too* quickly;** folks seeing the question might already be expending their hard-earned efforts to answer your question when it appeared. But if the question has been sitting there for awhile unanswered, it is okay to remove it if you have sufficient cause. But **please do not remove posts others may find useful or intriguing,** and the system won't let you removed an answered question that has been up-voted at all.

Comment: I allowed it a few days on the Electrical Engineering site. Then I allowed it a few days on the Physics site. Then I removed it which I shouldn't have. Now that it isn't there on any site, I think I should re post it on the Physics site since if anything, it's going to benefit future users. I will start a bounty on it when eligible. I hope that's fine.

Comment: I agree it's a bad idea to delete a new question. People might lose their effort. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: Can I encourage you to edit the third paragraph of this answer?  Migrating questions with answers is usually a bad idea, especially if they've been voted on a bunch, or if one of the answers has been accepted.  See http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/87031/160917 and http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/273585/160917 (bullet 5).  I realize this is a bit of a tangent from the main point of the question, but I'd prefer to avoid setting the wrong expectations around migration.