# So, no one cares about missing features on 10k tools?

Tags: discussion, 10k-tools

Previously, there were a lot of tool links on 10k tools:

> - posts flagged as offensive or spam
> - recently deleted posts
> - recently closed questions
> - recently imported questions
> - see all recent edits in chronological order
> - new posts by new users
> - questions with newly created tags
> - new answers to old questions
> - recent questions with most view velocity
> - recent questions with most edit velocity
> - recent questions with most vote velocity
> - recent wiki changes
> - recent wikis created
> - suggested edit stats

After [this implementation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89942/broken-links-on-the-10k-tools-page), now:

> - posts flagged as offensive or spam
> - recently deleted posts (basically gone, now just a link to delete tab)
> - recently closed questions (basically gone, now just a link to closed tab)
> - recently imported questions (basically gone, now just a link to stats tab)
> - new answers to old questions
> - suggested edit stats

I don't see any reports on meta about this yet, 
so, doesn't anyone care about missing features on 10k tools?

Comment: Aren't the missing tools all under /review. So they aren't missing, just no longer 10k only

Comment: Didn't YOU see this one? [Broken links on the 10K tools page](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/89942/155585)

Comment: All of those were broken links

Comment: I care... But I only learned of it *after* I read Nick's answer, explaining that they had been banished for good.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two main reasons. These were reports thrown in as a "bonus" on the 10k tools page that generally got **folded into** either

a) The 10k tools main pages

- or -

b) The /review functionality.

... *and* they were used very infrequently.

If you want some part of these bonus reports back, just make a case for it here.

Comment: Shameless plug: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89833/review-tab-suggestion-self-answers

Comment: I've made a hobby out of flagging "not an answer" answers. The "new posts from new users" was good for this. "First answers" doesn't quite work as well for this. The "self answers" suggestion in my previous comment would be a HUGE help. That, in conjunction with "late answers" would find tons of follow up posts and "me too" answers.

Comment: I definitely want “recently imported questions”. These questions almost always require attention, at least retagging. It doesn't have to be the same UI — I'd prefer something more convenient. [Making them appear in the chat](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81113/make-migrated-posts-be-part-of-chat-rss-feed) would be a good start.

Comment: @gilles if you are a moderator that's already available to you under `http://example.com/admin/posts/migrated/here`

Comment: @Jeff: Actually I want it on `/review` (i.e. for everyone). `/tools` (10k) was better than nothing. I use(d) it sometimes on Unix (where I'm not a ♦).

Comment: @JonsEvilTwin ~ Those should be commented on, rather than (in addition to?) being flagged.

Comment: The main ones I miss are "recently closed/deleted posts"; I used them to figure out stats about closed/deleted posts (how many posts have been migrated from SO to other sites in a given time frame, how many posts were closed by a mod versus by 5 votes, how many posts were deleted by the OP versus by votes, etc). I don't think there's a way to figure that information out anymore

Comment: @michael ok, set up a meta request with the specifics of what you need and make a case for it, and I will see that it happens.

Answer (score 9):

Well, like Nick said:

> The other routes were not used (we're talking < 10 times in 3 days *on the entire network*)

They removed them specifically because nobody used them, so naturally it's not going to cause a big controversy. Personally, I was in the habit of opening the first eight links and ignoring the rest; five still exist, new posts by new users is part of review, and new tags is part of stats. The only page I actually used that's gone now is recent edits, and I wasn't super attached to it

Comment: You are saying that nobody used *New posts by new users*? I used mostly only that one and *New answers to old questions*. Why is functionality causing no problems removed?

Comment: @Ladislav It was causing a problem, the pages were [broken](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89942/broken-links-on-the-10k-tools-page). Since both those pages already exist in the review tab now ([first answers](http://stackoverflow.com/review/first-answers?pagesize=15&filter=day), [first questions](http://stackoverflow.com/review/first-questions?pagesize=15&filter=day), [late answers](http://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers?pagesize=15&filter=day)), they just decided to delete the functionality from tools rather than fix it

Comment: Ok, I started related feature request: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90084/review-offer-expand-collapse-all

Answer (score 4):

Actually, I posted a bug about this, but deleted it as a dupe of [the original one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89942/broken-links-on-the-10k-tools-page).

And I VERY much miss the "new posts from new users" links, which I don't think is sufficiently addressed by the /review tabs. I mentioned this in [Nick's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89942/broken-links-on-the-10k-tools-page/89944#89944) on the broken links question, but he said the SE team wouldn't give it back.

What I would *really* like to see is a [review tab for self answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89833/review-tab-suggestion-self-answers).