# Review - offer expand / collapse all

Tags: feature-request, review, moderator-tools

Moderator tools was changed recently and *Review* is now considered as replacement of *New posts by new users*. I will be OK with that if it really offers same functionality. I don't like that I have to expand each post manually by clicking *Show full xxx*. What about adding functionality like expand / collapse all. It will simplify searching for posts which should be edited / formatted.

Comment: No longer relevant in the new /review queues; if there's functionality needed still that isn't available, more detail on *why* would be appropriate.