# Have Tool > Stats > Most viewed show the posts that got the most views in the last x days, regardless of post date

Tags: feature-request, 10k-tools

While peeking at the site analytics for Gaming, I noticed we suddenly got 3k referrals from StumbleUpon, 1.5k only this week.

- [Tools → Stats → Most visited](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tools?tab=stats&daterange=last7days) showed a question with only 1.2k views
- [No referral-based badges have been recently awarded](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/badges/189/announcer)
- The [StumbleUpon bookmark for the main site](http://www.stumbleupon.com/url/gaming.stackexchange.com/) only had 500 views... since February
- Their `site:` operator [only works when you add a search term](http://www.stumbleupon.com/search?q=site:gaming.stackexchange.com&x=0&y=0) and I couldn't find one (even searching for `how site:gaming.stackexchange.com`, `why site:gaming.stackexchange.com`, `what site:gaming.stackexchange.com`, etc., got no hits)
- Their tag based browsing [only lists 10 "discoveries" per category](http://www.stumbleupon.com/discover/video-games/10/)
- Google reported [no new pages](http://www.google.com/#q=site:stumbleupon.com+links:gaming.stackexchange.com&hl=en&tbo=1&qscrl=1&biw=1280&bih=919&output=search&source=lnt&tbs=qdr:m&sa=X&ei=XgLITdjBIISg-waHmPzVAQ&ved=0CAcQpwUoBA&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=6ab4216c4ada3168) created in the last 7 days (or last month) on StumbleUpon containing or linking to the site.

I took this with my fellow mods, but we weren't able to come up with anything and, after a while, we gave up. Grace [poked](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/950897#950897) Rebecca, and she took a moment to grep through her analytics to share with us what the [question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/20446/what-maps-correspond-to-what-test-chambers-in-portal-2) and the [bookmarks](http://www.stumbleupon.com/url/gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/20446/what-maps-correspond-to-what-test-chambers-in-portal-2) were.

Now, we could've saved a lot of time at step 1, if the Most Visited 10k-tools pane showed what questions got the most views in the last x days, as opposed to what questions got the most views *and were posted* in the last x days, which isn't very useful information. Alternatively we could've used the defunct "questions with the most views velocity" 10k tool, but [it silently received a pleasant death.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90068/so-no-one-cares-about-missing-features-on-10k-tools)

Can we then change the "most visited" pane in the stats tab to show questions with the most views in the last x days, regardless of post date?