# Remove redundant links from 10k Tools links page

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks, 10k-tools

[image: Image of the 10k tools, circling tabs and seemingly redundant links]

- posts flagged as offensive or spam
- recently deleted posts
- recently closed questions
- recently imported questions

Remove redundant links from 10k Tools links page, same can be done with one-click at tab bar too.

Instead all of those links should be at 10k privileges help page at

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/moderator-tools

Comment: Don't you think we've removed *enough* from the 10k tools already?

Answer (score 2):

I'd prefer to see the last three [produce full lists](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90068/so-no-one-cares-about-missing-features-on-10k-tools) rather than the last few days/weeks available on the "dashboard" pages. No, those weren't *often* useful, but on rare occasions they let you track down a question or compile some quick and dirty metrics that wouldn't have been possible without the extra data.